# Table Replication and Synchronization in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am pretty new to AZURE cloud and stuck at a place where I want to repplicate 1 table into another database with same schema and table name.

By replication I mean, the new table in another database should automatically synced with the original table. I can do this using the **elastic table**, but the queries are taking way too long and some time getting timed out, so I am thinking of having a local table in another database instead of elastic table, but I am not sure how I can do this in AZURE ?
Note: Both database resided on same DB server

Any example, links will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use a DACPAC (Data-Tier Package) a data tier package can be created in Visual Studio or extracted from an existing database. They contain the database creation scripts and manage your deltas for you. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=vsts&tabs=designer#dacpac). For information about how to build and deploy a DACPAC using both VS and extracted from a database [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804345/how-to-create-open-dac-application-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Thanks! But i have to keep the destination table in sync with source table all the time.

Comment: When you say the _elastic table_ do you mean elastic database query as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/)

Comment: Yes, that is the one

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure of another way, without using external tooling which seems excessive for the task. Sorry I couldn't help this time

Comment: There is a way out in azure, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync.
 But I am not able to configure this 1 :(

Comment: How are you unable to configure?

Comment: I did it, but the data is not flowing to destination table. Am Trying it hard :)